# How to print/show a dynamic value on an HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

So assuming that I have an Angular 4 component like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  printThisValue = 'customAttr';
  constructor(){}
}
```

How to I print the value inside an HTML tag just like this code seen below:

```
<div class="myStyle" {{ printThisValue }} ></div>
```

The HTML code above seems to not work. I'm aware that you are able to print the value like this:

```
<div class="myStyle">{{ printThisValue }}</div>
// or like this
<div class="myStyle {{ printThisValue }}"></div>
```

But how do I go about this?

Comment: Assuming you want to bind an attribute to a variable; If you know the name of the attribute you can do: ```<div class="myStyle" [attr.customAttr]="printThisValue"></div>```

Comment: Thanks @dotoconnor, that could work, but what about values having special characters like "[handle]",, cause that value that i wanted to add inside the tag has a special character, and i believe doing [attr.[handle]] or [attr."[handle]"] does not work. :(

Comment: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-custom-attribute-directive-example
Check this link, i hope you will get what you need

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There may be a better / easier way to do this, but you can create a directive that takes the name of the attribute and then sets it on the element.

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ 
  selector: '[customAttr]' 
})
export class CustomDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    @Input() customAttr;
    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
       this.elRef.nativeElement.setAttribute(this.customAttr, true);
    }       
}
```

Then you can use it like: `<div class="myStyle" [customAttr]="printThisValue">` and it will be emitted with `<div class="myStyle" customAttr>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate.

Answer (score 1):

Check which one can be your solution

Case 1 : **Conditional** attribute

```
<div class="myStyle" [attr.attr_name]="condition"></div>
```

Case 2 : Customized (**dynamic**) attribute **name**

> HTML (Template)

```
<div #elem1>
  {{ attachAttr }} Hi
</div>
```

> TypeScript of a Sample Component

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, QueryList, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  myAttr = "custom_attr"; // Customize attribute name

  attachAttr: any;

  @ViewChildren('elem1') elem;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.elem['first'].nativeElement.setAttribute(this.myAttr,"");
    }

}
```

**Output** will be

```
<div custom_attr> Hi </div>
```